# shell while loop is breaking abnormally

Tags: shell, loops, while-loop, openssl

I am writing a shell script to save ssl certificats for a list of domains. While loop is beaking early when openssl responds correcly.

```
#!/bin/bash
cat urls | while read url
do
    echo "processing $url ..."
    domain=`echo $url | cut -d'/' -f3 | cut -d':' -f1`
    timeout 30 openssl s_client -connect $domain:443 -servername $domain > $domain.pem 2>/dev/null
done
```

Here is an example of urls file:

```
 https://app.singstat.gov.sg/rss/rssfeed.aspx
 https://bugs.maemo.org/attachment.cgi?id=644
 https://www.audisaradarpb.com/sfp/SFP_EF_html/Portal/Public_Page/
 https://www.bankerstrust.com/news/index.html
```

Comment: `timeopen 30 openssl s_client ... </dev/null`. You don't want `openssl` to consume unprocessed elements of your URL list on stdin (treating those URLs as contents to send to the remote server).

Comment: (BTW, you've got a bunch of miscellaneous bugs here that http://shellcheck.net/ will catch -- none related to your problem, but all capable of resulting in... surprising... output given an interesting enough URL on input)

Comment: thank you charles Duffy , openssl consumes my input file, using </dev/null resolved my problèm